# Swing - How to add a JPopupMenu in a JTable Cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable, cell, jpopupmenu

I'd like to insert a JPopupMenu for each cell of a column of my JTable (to be able to select multiple items).
Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Are the values for each cell's popup different?

Comment: No, same values for the popups. I want some kind of combobox with multiple selection, each row can select several values from the PopupMenu

Answer (score 2):

For multiple selections within a cell, you'll need both a custom [renderer and editor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender). For the editor component, use a [`JList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) with the selection mode set to `MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION`. The renderer should display something appropriate for the content, e.g. a comma-separated list of values. Note that the data for each row must be stored in the `TableModel`, not in the renderer and editor itself. The details will depend on your data model, but `List<String>` or `EnumSet<String>` may be appropriate.